# Need of semiconductor instead of conductors for changing conductivity

Tags: semiconductors, conductivity, conductors, metal

Is changing conductivity is one of the reason to use semiconductors?

When we can change conductivity of metals(by some means) then why do we need semiconductors instead in most of the electronic devices

Comment: What means of changing conductivity of metals are you thinking of? By what % can you change it? Can you change it by controlling it with a small current?

Comment: *When we can change conductivity of metals* OK, show us an example and then show us how a device can be made using that principle to amplify a small electrical signal. If you've got that working, does it perform as well (same or more power amplification, same or lower power consumption) than a semiconductor device? My money is still on the semiconductors but if you have a better way feel free to share.

Comment: To be useful we would need to be able to change conductivity in a controlled and incrementally variable fashion over several orders of magnitude. The BJT transistor was created in 1950 so if there was an better alternative there have been about 70 years to discover it.

Comment: I think you can change the conductivity of mercury vapour with a low power control signal, see the exhibit in the science museum, but it is filling a large glass tube with electrodes that looks awfully like an old style valve. Otherwise, we might be able to struggle to 1% variation in solid metals, with temperature modulation or Hall effect and the consumption of vast power. Semiconductors OTOH give decades and decades of variability, with small power consumption.

Comment: It's easy to change the conductivity of metals : it's commonly a function of temperature, for example, so it can be altered by changing the current density in the metal. This changes the power dissipation, hence the temperature, and hence the conductivity. Beyond this, it's unclear what point you are making or trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

"If my grandmother had wheels, she'd be a wagon".

The semiconductors are used because of their particular properties. This is usually silicon, but doesn't have to be; see germanium diodes, gallium arsenide, cadmium telluride, silicon carbide and so on.

> When we can change conductivity of metals(by some means)

It's not even clear what tense this is in; do you mean we can *currently* change the conductivity of metals? I don't think so. Or if something in the future is developed?

What do you call a metal whose conductivity can be changed? A semiconductor.

Comment: I think we can change the conductivity of metals. Response time or energy efficiency are another matter...